# How to select default dropdown option in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to select dropdown in angularjs ?

How to select default dropdown option for "Third Project 456"

Please Check :[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bschauhan/6L16g7bn/)

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-change="getMileWorkerlist(broadcastManagerData.project_list)" ng-model="broadcastManagerData.project_list" name="project_list" class="form-control" required >
<option value="0">All Project</option>
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" ng-value="key">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$scope.projectList = {
35: "Third Project 456",
56: "Project-11-1-2016",
76: "test project for cbs"
};
$scope.broadcastManagerData.project_list =35;
```

**Make my html in view source:**

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required="" name="project_list" ng-model="broadcastManagerData.project_list" ng-change="getMileWorkerlist(broadcastManagerData.project_list)">
<option value="? number:35 ?"></option>
<option ng-selected="true" ng-value="0" value="0" selected="selected">All Project</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-value="key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="35">Third Project 456</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-value="key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="56">Project-11-1-2016</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-value="key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="76">test project for cbs</option>
</select>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Please Check :[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bschauhan/6L16g7bn/)

Comment: try something like `ng-init="broadcastManagerData.project_list = projectList[0]"` .. so index 0 in projectList, write this after ng-repeat. See [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: it's not working..i know this thing. but, something wrong in this case.

Comment: It's Wroking: <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="broadcastManagerData.project_list = 'Third Project 456'">
     <select ng-model="broadcastManagerData.project_list"  >
      <option value="0">All Project</option>
      <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" ng-value="value" ng-selected="value=='Third Project 456'">{{value}}</option>
    </select>
    {{broadcastManagerData.project_list}}
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working..i know this thing. but, something wrong in this case.

Comment: It's Wroking: <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>

Answer (score 1):

Well I know why my comment was not working, I assumed (didn't read question carefully) that you were working with an array, and you're not. I do not know how to do it using (key, value), but why are you not using an array? If you were, this would work:

```
<select ng-change="getMileWorkerlist(broadcastManagerData.project_list)"
  ng-model="broadcastManagerData.project_list"
  ng-init="broadcastManagerData.project_list = projectList[0].key" 
  name="project_list"  class="form-control" required 
  ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in projectList">
</select>
```

and in controller, the array:

```
$scope.projectList = [
    {key: 35, value: "Third Project 456"},
    {key: 56, value: "Project-11-1-2016"},
    {key: 76, value: "test project for cbs"}
];
```

But as I said, seems like this way only works with an array. Any reason why you can't do it this way?

Comment: I forked your fiddle to use my code: https://jsfiddle.net/q1fpny5j/ .. But you must understand that I changed the `projectList` to become an array using [ ] instead of { }

Comment: Friends i have not use "ng-options"

Comment: It's Wroking: <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below will help:

`<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" ng-value="key" ng-selected="value == 'Third Project 456'">{{value}}</option>`

Comment: it's not working..i know this thing. but, something wrong in this case.

Comment: It's Wroking: <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>

Comment: @BharatChauhan In the fiddle, you didn't add the ng-selected directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-change="getMileWorkerlist(broadcastManagerData.project_list)" ng-model="broadcastManagerData.project_list" name="project_list" class="form-control" required >
<option value="0">All Project</option>
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in projectList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```